# Send data over network to multiple recipient parallely

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, opencv, networking, network-programming

Hellow, i'm working with network programing and it's been so hard to create a logic that allows to stream a video from a single server to multiple clients **with no delay**.

which means that i have to implement a parallel execution during the stream to all connected clients in order to display the images at the same time.

and why is that important for my project it's because i'm intending to have large number of clients (from 200 to approximately 700), now with 10 clients that delay is nothing but with 700 clients could significantly increase the delay to several minutes (not sure but possible).

for those who don't know what's the cause of the dely, it's from the **for loop** that i'm using which contain the send function for each frame, and that is a serial execution.

i tried **threading** and **multiprocessing** and even **function schedule** but every thing got messy, previously i was using **socket** & **opencv**, but for some reason it caused issues during the streaming, now i switched to **Netgear** & **Vidgear** but i'm still struggling.

Hope someone can help.

PS: multicast is just not right for the job, after i tried it i was receiving errors because of the length of the transmitted images, UDP protocol will **NOT** accept more then 65535 byte.

Comment: Are the clients on the same network? Are groups of clients on the same network?

Comment: the server and the clients in the same network

Comment: Because everything is in the same network, then you should use multicast, which is designed for such a scenario. You can send a single multicast packet to as many receivers as are subscribed to that multicast group. Forget trying to send copies of the same data to each client, just send it once, and all the clients will receive it.

Comment: thank you so much for the information, i'll start doing some tests with your recommendation and hopefully everything goes as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment, everything is in the same network, and we have multicast for exactly your problem. Rather than sending the same data over and over to multiple hosts, you can send a single stream of traffic to many receivers.

You set up the clients to subscribe to a multicast group, normally a group in the `239.0.0.0/8` Organization-Local scope. Your server then sends its traffic to the same multicast group to which the clients have subscribed. The single traffic stream will be received and processed by every client subscribed to the multicast group.

Because multicast sends to multiple clients, you must use a connectionless transport protocol, e.g. UDP. Connection-oriented transport protocols, e.g. TCP, create connections between two hosts, so they cannot be used with multicast, which is one-to-many.

By default, multicast only works in the same network. We do have multicast routing to send traffic to other networks, but it is very different than the usual unicast routing. Also, you cannot multicast on the public Internet because the ISPs do not have multicast routing. You can multicast to a different site across the Internet by using a tunnel that supports multicast, e.g. GRE. Both the source and destination routers need to be configured for multicast routing, as well as any routers in the path of the multicast packets (the Internet routers on see the unicast tunnel packets, not the multicast packets, so you can send the multicast across the Internet).

Comment: thank you very much you have shared some important informations, and you where very precise about the topic, i really do appreciate it.

Comment: unfortunately UDP can't send large data, when i stream video and the data length reaches 55000 it throws an error, any way to handle that ?

Comment: UDP is not a streaming protocol, it is message-based. You simply need the application to or have an application-layer protocol to break the data into smaller chunks for UDP. TCP is a streaming protocol, but it creates connections between only two hosts. There are application-layer protocols that will stream on top of UDP for things like video.

Comment: could you please post an example for such application-layer protocol to break the data into smaller chunks for UDP for both sender code & receiver code

Answer (score 0):

> Hellow, i'm working with network programing and it's been so hard to create a logic that allows to stream a video from a single server to multiple clients with no delay.

Hey @zaki-lazhari I'm the creator of [VidGear](https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear) Video Processing Python Project. Actually, **NetGear is not right API choice for multi-casting task, instead you should be using [WebGear API](https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/gears/webgear/overview/)**. WebGear can acts as powerful Video Streaming Server that transfers live video-frames to any web browser on a network. So you can easily setup WebGear Server in few lines of code as follows:

```
# import required libraries
import uvicorn
from vidgear.gears.asyncio import WebGear

#various performance tweaks
options={"frame_size_reduction": 40, "frame_jpeg_quality": 80, "frame_jpeg_optimize": True, "frame_jpeg_progressive": False}

#initialize WebGear app  
web=WebGear(source="foo.mp4", logging=True, **options)

#run this app on Uvicorn server at address http://0.0.0.0:8000/
uvicorn.run(web(), host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)

#close app safely
web.shutdown()
```

So every device *(even a smartphone with any browser installed)* on the same network can access real-time frames on there browser without any extra dependencies. **More code samples can be found here:** https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/gears/webgear/advanced/

*Hope it helps. Good luck!*